# Launch screen on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen, launch

I have an iPhone app. When I run it on the iPad everything looks great (but small) except for the launch screen that also is small (not full screen) and not really proportional.

I have read the documentation, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I have added Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png, but it doesn't change anything.

I don't really mind about how it is, more than I don't want it to be rejected in App Store because of that.

Edit: My info.plist (if you see other weird things, please let me know. I'm submitting today)

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array/>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small-50.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.xx.xxx</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1234</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainWindow</string>
<key>SHKFacebookKey</key>
<string>1234</string>
<key>SHKFacebookSecret</key>
<string>1234</string>
<key>SHKMyAppName</key>
<string>xxx</string>
<key>SHKMyAppURL</key>
<string>http://itunes.apple.com/xxx</string>
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array/>
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array/>
```

Comment: Are you developing a universal app or an iPhone app that also runs on the iPad?

Comment: It's just for iPhone, but I want it to be ok on iPad too. I will do a separate iPad or universal later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add these into your Info.plist file

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Even of your orientations work properly without, it's absolutely imperative to have these to select a proper launch screen.

BTW You won't be rejected. It's just a matter of good programming ethics.

Comment: I have done that, but no difference. It still looks like the launch-screen is taken from a square icon, not the iphone launch pictures or the big iPad format ones I also provided.

Comment: "Not rejected". That's what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: Other than you list `<string>Icon-72.png</string>` 3 times, nothing suspicious. Now do me a favor. Delete your app in Simulator, clean and build the project again. Run it in sim. `ps -ef | grep name_of_your_project`. Find location and see if you have all 4 files in your application bundle.

Comment: Xcode generated the extra Icon-72 when I tried to add iPad icon in the GUI. I removed it now. Thanks. I'm not sure if I understand the other part. I did like you said, wrote that line in Terminal and got this response: 501 15964 15958   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep MyProject

Comment: type the actual name of your program, and expect to see  /Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/4AA31BD3-2A7B-4406-8F9B-F66D73D4B141/APP_Test.app, which will give you path to application bundle within your simulator.

Comment: Ok, I found it. Everything seems to be in there, except for Icon-72.png (but Icon-iPad.png is). Default-Portrait.png and Default.Landscape.png is there.